Cancel updates when cancelling a rollout
My expectation was when you paused or deleted a rollout all running actions for all targets included in the rollout would be cancelled. Only for scheduled actions the actions are cancelled. How can I cancel for ALL actions, even the running once?
Found this https://www.eclipse.org/lists/hawkbit-dev/msg00086.html but couldn't find any answer.
I paused a rollout and realized that products were still updated.
